# Tower defense endless levels logic sprite kit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, performance

I am making a tower defense game for iOS using Sprite Kit. I was wondering if there was an efficient and concise way of coding the game so that there are an endless amount of levels like in Bloons TD 5.

I am not asking for code, but I am asking if there ***is*** a way to code this concept into the game. I am just starting out with coding iOS games, and I want to learn efficient ways of doing complicated concepts like this. So, can you give me some ideas to start out with to create this?

Comment: i suppose it depends on how your difficulty scales, you could essentially increase the difficulty of every level by a constant factor (if linear difficulty for example). essentially you'd be iterating through every level, increasing difficulty, until a certain condition is met (in this instance, player loses all his lives)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this you don't need any specific library, you need to build your levels with some generality - make them scaleable.

For example in your function that sets up/executes the level the number of enemies is a variable that you increment as the user advances. See the sudo-code example below:

```
// Level loop
NSInteger numberOfWaves = 1;
NSInteger secondsBetweenWaves = 60;
BOOL success = YES;
while (success) {
    success = level(numberOfWaves, secondsBetweenWaves);
    numberOfWaves += 2;
    secondsBetweenWaves = (secondsBetweenWaves > 0) ? secondsBetweenWaves - 1 : 0; // don't have negative time
}
```

I hope this helps give you some ideas for starting your algorithm.

Beginners often get frustrated visualizing algorithms for accomplishing a task - don't give up! Just be patient and take time to sketch out your logic on paper before you go to code. Only time programming will help you get better at this.

Good Luck!